# Unable to convert dll's from .Net v2.0.0.0 to v3.5.0.0

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to add this [custom tab control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) to my **v3.5** Windows CE C# application. The custom tab control project is written for regular Windows forms and cannot be added directly to my Windows CE project.

I tried creating a v3.5 Windows CE class library and copy/paste the code over. The problem is that I have to downgrade **system.dll, system.drawing.dll and system.windows.forms.dll** to the **2.0.0.0** versions because **v3.5** was missing attributes such as System.ComponentModel.**ToolboxItem**, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.**GraphicsPath** and System.Windows.Forms.**VisualStyles**... (The source code was using v2.0.0.0 as well with target framework set to v3.5)

After replacing them and compiling the class library, I added the new custom tab control to my v3.5 Windows CE project's toolbox. My project now also complains and wants me to use the **v2.0** dll's :

> The type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

After downgrading my project too, the project compiles but can no longer run on my **v3.5** Windows CE mobile device... I've read many forums that state **v2.0** projects can run on **v3.5** platforms, but it's not the case for me. Can someone show me how to successfully transition to the **v3.5** dll's?

Comment: You are trying to use classes that can only work on a desktop machine.  Delete that code from your machine so it can no longer do any further harm.

Comment: I tried to convert them to a Windows CE class library but failed, is there a way to get around that rather than building my own custom control from scratch?